# Проблемы с запросами

Tags: python, requests, steam

Есть 2 запроса,их необходимо сравнить.
1:

```
    {"success":true,"hash":"2707772634/kxuw2oFFFf8","offer":{"partner":"877050581","token":"LE5HuwZk","tradeoffermessage":"32Z6 ... /trade/2707772634/kxuw2oFFFf8/","items":[{"appid":730,"contextid":2,"assetid":"16409501459","amount":1}]}}



2 Очень большой:{"response":{"trade_offers_sent":[{"tradeofferid":"3669793079","accountid_other":922836416,"message":"E9V8 ... /trade/2707784514/u2FjLxt1vNU/","expiration_time":1567092461,"trade_offer_state":9,"items_to_give":[{"appid":730,"contextid":"2","assetid":"16409431301","classid":"1560432824","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","missing":false,"est_usd":"35"}],"is_our_offer":true,"time_created":1565882861,"time_updated":1565882861,"from_real_time_trade":false,"escrow_end_date":0,"confirmation_method":2}
```

необходимо сравнить в 1 tradeoffermessage,во 2 message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно прописать цепочку ключей. d1 это первый, d2 это второй. [0] в d2 это обращение к элементу списка.

```
d1["offer"]["tradeoffermessage"]==d2["response"]["trade_offers_sent"][0]["message"])
```